# Rails 4/ERB if/else loop gives unexpected ;, expected : error, if I add html or text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a mobile app in Rails 4/ERB where people can post and comment on others' posts. I'd like to be able to toggle the visibility of comments using jQuery, but whenever I attempt to wrap the each loop in a div tag, or add comments count, I get an error. ('comments/comment' is a partial containing the template for the actual comment)

This works, but shows all the comments (not what I want):

```
 <% if post.comments.count > 0? %>
   <% post.comments.order(:created_at).reverse.each do |comment| %>
     <%= render 'comments/comment', comment: comment %>
   <% end %>
 <%:%>
   No comments yet.
 <% end %>
```

this gives me an unexpected semicolon error:

```
 <% if post.comments.count > 0? %>
   <%= post.comments.count %> Comments.
   <% post.comments.order(:created_at).reverse.each do |comment| %>
     <%= render 'comments/comment', comment: comment %>
   <% end %>
 <%:%>
  No comments yet.
 <% end %>
```

so does this:

```
<% if post.comments.count > 0? %>
 <div>
   <% post.comments.order(:created_at).reverse.each do |comment| %>
     <%= render 'comments/comment', comment: comment %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
 <%:%>
    No comments yet.
 <% end %>
```

the exact words of the error are `syntax error, unexpected ;, expected :`

What am I doing wrong, and how can I use HTML within this block without it throwing an error at me? Any help would be much appreciated.

addendum: oddly enough, if I stick the comment count code inside the each loop, it works (but, because it's an each loop, displays it multiple times)

addendum 2: even this gives an error:

```
<%= render 'comments/form',post: post%></p>
  <% if post.comments.count > 0? %>
    <!--<%= post.comments.count %> Comments. -->
    <% post.comments.order(:created_at).reverse.each do |comment| %>
      <%= render 'comments/comment', comment: comment %>
    <% end %>
  <%:%>
   No comments yet.
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Why are you using `<%:%>` instead of `<% else %>`?

Comment: else throws an error, unexpected keywoord_else, expected :

Comment: Could it be the question mark after the posts.comments.count > 0?  The greater than already returns a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<%= render 'comments/form',post: post%></p>
 <% if post.comments.count > 0 %>
  <!--<%= post.comments.count %> Comments. -->
  <% post.comments.order(:created_at).reverse.each do |comment| %>
    <%= render 'comments/comment', comment: comment %>
  <% end %>
<%else%>
 <!-- No comments yet. --->
<% end %>
```

remove `?` in 2nd line because `post.comments.count > 0` this will return `true` or `false`,so need to check again.

so,now you can use `else` condition.

Answer (score 0):

As others have alluded to, the snippet `if post.comments.count > 0?` implies that you want to use the ruby [ternary ?: operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm). As its name implies, the ternary ?: operator is composed of 3 parts:

1. the condition
2. value if the condition is true
3. value if the condition is false

Here's an example of its use:

`is_even = (num % 2) ? true : false`

Note that in this example both the if check (`?`) and else (`:`) are included, as is required by the ternary operator. So the issue with your use of `?` is that you're using the if check, but not the else check.